# How to work with Mahout?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloud, mahout, recommendation-engine

I have tried to work with mahout using the link:
http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.in/2010/11/apache-mahout.html

When i execute the command

`anand@ubuntu:~/Downloads/mahout-distribution-0.9$ bin/mahout recommenditembased --input mydata.dat --usersFile user.dat --numRecommendations 2 --output output/ --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORRELATION`

it shows:

`hadoop binary is not in PATH,HADOOP_HOME/bin,HADOOP_PREFIX/bin, running locally
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

What may be the possible reasons for the errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Apache Hadoop first ( also described [here](http://tuxdna.in/files/notes/hadoop.html#setup) ):

```
$ http://mirror.metrocast.net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-1.2.1-bin.tar.gz
$ tar zxf hadoop-1.2.1-bin.tar.gz
$ cd hadoop-1.2.1
$ export PATH=`pwd`/bin:$PATH
```

Then try to setup Apache Mahout

Apache Mahout setup

```
$ wget -c http://archive.apache.org/dist/mahout/0.9/mahout-distribution-0.9.tar.gz
$ tar zxf mahout-distribution-0.9.tar.gz
$ cd mahout-distribution-0.9
```

Setup env variables:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/hadoop-1.2.1
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
export MAHOUT_HOME=/path/to/mahout-distribution-0.9
export PATH=$MAHOUT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now your Mahout installation should work fine ( read [here](https://github.com/tuxdna/mahout-book/blob/master/setup.asciidoc) for more ).